# How to enable again the download approach about "Attach Source"?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, m2eclipse, spring-tools-4

For a Spring project, developed through Spring Tool Suite 4 (based on Eclipse), for any Java file and for any part of its code, such as:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
   ...
}
```

When the mouse's cursor is over a Spring type - such as `@Configuration` - and is accomplished the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click approach then the source code is opened but according with the following process:

1. Is loaded/shown a kind of "binary" data showing: `Class File Editor - Source not found`, the `Attach Source...` button and as indicated the "binary" data.
2. After of either 1 or 2 seconds ***immediately*** is downloaded and shown the source code. As observation while the downloading process happens, in the same Window at the right bottom is shown the progress to download.

*Since long time ago* I don't have the following situation: for only a specific *workspace* (among others) the source code remains at the first point.

**Observation**: The project is based on Maven and about its settings:

```
Preferences
 Maven
  ...
  Download Artifact Sources (is unchecked)
  Download Artifact Javadoc (is unchecked)
  ...
```

All the workspaces where the downloading process happens have the same setting shown above. Therefore in other place something was changed.

What could be misconfigured and how to fix it?

Comment: probably more of a Maven Integration question, therefore added the m2e tag

Comment: Thanks for the upgrade ... agree with your comment, but lets assume that perhaps the IDE itself would be overriding something ... or perhaps vice versa